# What is this magic client string in AzureDevOps Python REST API?

Tags: python, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Python REST API for Azure DevOps (https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api), there is only a single example given to parse the list of projects:

```
from vsts.vss_connection import VssConnection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = 'YOURPAT'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/YOURORG'

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = VssConnection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
core_client = connection.get_client('vsts.core.v4_0.core_client.CoreClient')
```

Where is this string `'vsts.core.v4_0.core_client.CoreClient'` coming from?

And more importantly, what is the corresponding "magic string" for manipulating:

- WorkItems
- Test Runs and Results
- Tasks
- Builds
- etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This magic string is coming from the folders organization of `vsts` module.

[image: Folder for core client]

It is the path with:

- indication of folder hierarchy with dots `.`
- the name of the Class at the end

For example, on my PC, I have the class "`CoreClient"` in the file *C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\vsts\core\v4_0\core_client.py*. That would give the magic string `'vsts.core.v4_0.core_client.CoreClient'` (which happens to be the one in the example).

By doing some further exploration, I have found out following strings (I use API version 4.1):

- **Workitems**:
  `"vsts.work_item_tracking.v4_1.work_item_tracking_client.WorkItemTrackingClient"`
- **Test Runs/Results**:
  `"vsts.test.v4_1.test_client.TestClient"`
- **Tasks** (to be checked):
  `"vsts.task.v4_1.task_client.TaskClient"`